# Why does the integral in the arch of the semicircunference of radius $R$ and center $0$ of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$ go to $0$ when $R$ goes to $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Why does the integral in the arch of the semicircunference of radius $R$ and center $0$ of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$ go to $0$ when $R$ goes to $0$?

I know it's true but I can't prove it by bounding it. It's to calculate an integral by using the residue theorem.

Comment: A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex contour integration of $\frac{e^{iz}}{z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3302580/complex-contour-integration-of-fraceizz)

Comment: @AnotherUser ty but I need it for when R goes to zero

Answer (score 1):

Write $e^{iz}/z = 1/z + O(1)$ so that the integral equals $\int_{S_R}1/z\,dz + O(R) = i\pi + O(R) \to i\pi$ as $R \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz=\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{iRe^{it}}}{Re^{it}}iRe^{it}dt=\int_0^\pi e^{iRe^{it}}idt.$$ Now take absolute value, so
$$\left|\int_0^\pi e^{iRe^{it}}idt\right|\leq\int_0^\pi |e^{iRe^{it}}|dt=\int_0^\pi |e^{-R\sin t}|dt=\int_0^\pi e^{-R\sin t}dt=2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-R\sin t}dt\\ \leq2\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} e^{-2Rt/\pi}dt=\frac{-\pi}{R}(e^{-R}-1).$$ So $$\left|\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz\right|\leq\frac{-\pi}{R}(e^{-R}-1),$$ which clearly goes to zero as $R$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to prove it when R goes to 0.

Comment: Are you sure? It does not make much sense to calculate that integral when R goes to zero. Could you post the whole question?

Comment: It's to calculate the real integral of sinx/x from -infinity to infinity, so you integrate in this path: [-r,-R], the semicircunference radius R and center 0, [R,r] and the semicircunference of radius r center 0, with r>R. The second semicircunference clearly goes to zero when r goes to infinity but then I need to prove the first one goes to zero when R goes to zero.

Comment: @Íñigo The $r\to0^+$ behaviour is a bit different, but still calculable. In this one-sided limit, $\exp(iRe^{it})\to1$, so the integral $\to\int_0^\pi1dt=\pi$. See also Theorem 9.13 [here](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/18.04/notes/topic9.pdf).